# Norm (modulus) of the derivative of complex function and Newton Method

Tags: complex-numbers, computational-mathematics, newton-raphson

I am implementing a function that approximates a root of a complex function, say $f(z)$. As we know, at iteration $i$ we ave

$$z_i = z_{i-1} - \frac{f(z_{i-1})}{f'(z_{i-1})}$$

The division of complex implies that we should have a division by the norm (modulus) of $f'(z_{i-1})$ but sometimes this norm gets little enough so it is so close to zero that it passes the double precision and it is zero for the computer. 
I won't like to deal with numbers with more precision than that. I was wondering if there is any motive to a point that gives a derivtive with norm 0 to not convert to a root. I mean, is there any geometric motive or something like that? What is the interpretation of the modulus of the derivative of a complex function be 0?

I am sorry for the question formulated like that, but I am not used to work with complex number, further derivatives of complex.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you asking about the geometrical interpretation of the Newton-Raphson method of root approximation?

Comment: No, It is more like the interpretation of the modulus of the derivative of a complex function to approaches 0

Comment: Are you trying to use Newtons method to find a root $z$ where $f(z) = f'(z) = 0$ ? In that case $\frac{f(w)}{f'(w)} \approx \frac{f'(w)}{f''(w)}$ for $w$ close to $z$ which might be a useful approximation when you are close to the root.